# Defining correlated inputs as constraints in an optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization, bayesian

I have an optimization problem:

```
min f(a, b, c)
```

subject to: `(a < constant_1) & (b + c < constant_2)`.

My understanding from optimization algorithms is that they try {(a_1, b_1, c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_2), ... (a_n, b_n, c_n)} and output the one which gives the most appropriate results.

My additional constraint is that if I define df =

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_1 | b_1 | c_1 |
| a_2 | b_2 | c_2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| a_n | b_n | c_n |

I want df has a fixed correlated matrix as R.

How can I add this constraint to my optimization problem, specifically if I want to use python for solving it?

Comment: Not sure what correlation means if the solver returns 1 point.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I edited my question to be more clear. Can you please take another look on that.